# File path in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, path

This is probably a basic question. I am new to Js. I am trying to require db.js in my tasks.js file. My file structure is as follows.

```
server
   routes
      api
        tasks.js
db.js
```

I am currently doing

```
const sql = require(path.join(__dirname, '/../db.js'));
```

This does not allow me to get above the routes folder. If anyone can explain this to me because I am struggling to figure this out without trial and error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is prefix the path with enough `../` sequences.

```
const sql = require('../../../db.js');
```

You won't need to use `path.join` or `__dirname` when using the `require` function.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely a security measure. If db.js is accessible, then try to specify it with an absolute path name, rather than a relative path name.